# Frequency relationship matrix

Tags: r, excel

I have a data set that looks like the following:

```
col1  |  col2    |  col3
A     |  yellow  |  ID1
B     |  yellow  |  ID1
A     |  red     |  ID2
C     |  blue    |  ID2
```

and what I'd like is a matrix where I can see how many IDs are in common between A and B, A and C and so on.

```
   |  A   |  B   |  C
A  |  --  |  1   |  1
B  |  1   |  --  |  0
C  |  1   |  0   |  --
```

Something like the above.
I think that there's an appropriate name for this structure but I couldn't find it.
I'm looking for a solution either with Excel (preferred) or R.
What would be the simplest way to do this?

The following question would be how would I know which IDs are in common?

Answer (score 4):

You could do:

```
m <- df[,-2]
m <- table(m)
m <- m %*% t(m)
diag(m) <- NA
#   col1
# col1 A  B  C
#   A NA  1  1
#   B  1 NA  0
#   C  1  0 NA
```

Key terms to search for might be incidence matrix, bipartite network/affiliation network, two-mode network to one-mode network, and adjacency matrix.

Data used:

```
df<-read.table(header=T,sep="|",text="col1|col2|col3
A|yellow|ID1
B|yellow|ID1
A|red|ID2
C|blue|ID2")
```